# Why is my Ubuntu laptop freezing suddenly?

Tags: screen, freeze, wayland, logout

Everything was working great till a few hours ago when I was prompted to restart my computer after the latest auto-update. After restarting the laptop when I clicked on an app the screen flickered and the computer GUI froze so I had to do a hard restart.

Now, if I use the 'Ubuntu on Wayland' option while logging in, then I can still open a few apps like System Monitor, Files, Terminal, Text Editor, Image Viewer, LibreOffice Writer, but if I try to open Firefox browser or Chromium browser or VLC player or GIMP or qBitTorrent or other such heavy apps, then the system freezes and/or logs me out.

If I use the default 'Ubuntu' option while logging in, then I am not able to open ANY app. The system just freezes and I have to do a hard restart.

How to fix this? Please help.

Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal Fossa)
Dell Laptop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allo. I got this problem too, few hours ago, and I solved it.
This is caused by new **Linux (here 5.8.0-34)** update.

All you should do is to use old version by making it default boot or remove that version.

To remove new version, Boot into old Linux (here 5.4.0-59), through "Advanced Options for Ubuntu" in GRUB Menu.

Use "Synpatic Package Manager" and remove ***linux-headers-x, linux-image-x, linux-modules-x, linux-modules-extra-x***, and any other removable with that version name. (x is your new version)

This will make old linux version as default.
Also, this will remove meta packages, so they won't get updates.
To fix this, install **linux-generic** or use **"sudo apt install linux-generic"**. It is dummy package and will install meta packages:- linux-headers-generic, linux-image-generic.

I am not a linux professional, this is an easy and temporary solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The issue was exactly as described and your solution worked perfectly.